# Htaccess + regex - server returns 500 Internal Server error

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have following regex:

```
^(?:([a-z]{2})\/)?.*?(?:\/?([\w\-]+))$
```

which basically means that I want to capture the two-letter language code and the last string after the slash.

It uses an answer from different question. I could not return matches in a reversed order so settled for the last one.

Unfortunately my server returns **500 Internal Server Error**. I tested it and it looks that it doesn't like the star * in the middle of the regex.

It also doesn't like `.+` if I insert it instead of `.*`

Below example URLs:

```
page
page/page1
page/page2/page3

en
en/page
en/page/page2
en/page/page2/page3
```

I would like the matches to be:

```
page
page1
page3

en
en & page
en & page2
en & page3
```

I do not understand why * or + would make server crash. I couldn't find any details, so hoping somebody can shed some light.

Link to Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/hW9eZ4/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use rule with a regex that uses [branch reset group feature of PCRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?|([a-z]{2})|(?:([a-z]{2})/)?.*?([\w-]+))/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW9eZ4/13)

I have tested in my Apache and it works pretty well. Make sure to comment all other rules while testing this.

Comment: I forgot to add one instance, for which your regex won't work I think. It's if in the URL there's only language like `/no` `/en` as well as just a page name like `/test6`

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully that makes more sense now

Comment: Wow I was looking for something like that but I never stumbled upon branch reset. I see that it's exactly what I want but I sent it to the hosting people as it doesn't work on my server for some reason

Comment: part of the question is why the server wouldn't accept such regex so I'm still working on that

Comment: The rule I have posted is already tested on my Apache. For any 500 error first thing to do is to check your Apache `error.log` and find corresponding error entry.

Comment: Very strange behaviour, I got the rule to work and not give me 500 error, but if I just leave `RewriteEngine on` + your rule, all my resources like `/_scripts/script.js` are getting 404. Trying to figure out how one rule could fail other resources in the absence of other rules

Comment: After a while I finally came back to this topic. Turns out I'm getting a 500 error when I add `/` before `index.php` but without the slash I am getting `php` as the output of `$_GET["b"]` it only happens when I don't put anything after the domain, other URLs seem to work

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before this `RewriteRule`

Comment: It's working.. thank you! And thousands more for answering within 5 minutes of my comment